# How to get from Belize City to Tikal?

Tags: transportation, buses, central-america, belize, tikal

I have heard and read many things about how dangerous Belize City is. I want to get to my destination, Tikal, as soon as possible once I land in Belize City. However, the only bus company that I am able to find that takes me to Santa Elena/Flores (nearest bust station to Tikal) is [this bus company](http://grupofuentedelnorte.com/index.php/itinerarios). According to their website, the only  time they go to Santa Elena is at 10 in the morning. However, my flight lands just a few hours after that.

I am *very* concerned for my safety. Could someone please help me find a bus on this same day with directions on how to get from Belize City Airport to the bus station?

Comment: The usual advice for scared first timers in Central America is to take a taxi directly from the airport to your hotel and a taxi directly from your hotel to the bus station the next morning. Belize City is the only capital city I haven't explored in Central America though. (I haven't been to Belmopan either.)

Comment: @hippietrail That brings up two concerns though: 1.) Getting ripped off by the taxi driver and 2.) I'm on a tight budget. :(

Comment: Central America is a place where you really have to consider the trade-offs between budget and safety. But you can always ask specific questions right here about taxis and safety at that airport and in that city! (I personally never take taxis when I travel, even where they are super cheap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread on [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1615369) discussing exactly this topic.  Which refers to 2 bus lines that offer service between Belize and Santa Helena/Flores/Tikal in Guatemala.

> Express Buses – Flores / Belize / Chetumal
>
> Two Guatemalan bus companies, San Juan Express Bus Service and Linea Dorada, provide bus service between Flores, Belize City and Chetumal; they do not make any other scheduled stops in Belize. In Belize City, buses arrive at and depart from the Belize City Water Taxi / Marine Terminal on North Front Street near the Swing Bridge. Buses operate on Sundays and public holidays. Not all buses are air-conditioned. The schedule below was in effect on 20 December 2007 but always confirm times before travel.

The thread is from back in 2008 so information is a bit dated but I was able to find the companies [Linea Dorada](http://www.lineadorada.info/) seem to offer a stop in Belize but on [only one of its routes](http://www.lineadorada.info/rutas-y-precios/de-santa-elena-hacia) and it may not work for you timewise, the other seems to be discussed at length on [Tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g562625-i16186-k5723997-Avoid_San_Juan_Travel_Agency-Flores_Peten_Department.html) and not under the best of terms.

There is a sort of [3rd party information site](http://belizebus.wordpress.com/) information on which I can't verify but it gives you some contact information for both companies listed above so you can check prices and schedules as needed.

One other company that is mentioned in the [TripAdvisor article](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g562625-i16186-k5723997-Avoid_San_Juan_Travel_Agency-Flores_Peten_Department.html) is [Adrenalina Tours](http://www.adrenalinatours.com/shuttles/from-flores-peten-to.html), which actually does offer a shuttle from Belize to Flores for $28 the only thing is I can't seem to find the schedule of when it leaves Belize but you can try contacting them to check.